# How to apply lambda function on multiple columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I always convert the columns into floats, by

```
prices['Open'] = prices['Open'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
prices['Close'] = prices['Close'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
prices['High'] = prices['High'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
prices['Low'] = prices['Low'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
prices['Volume'] = prices['Volume'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
prices['Market cap'] = prices['Market cap'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

I want to be able to do this in one line, i tried using

```
prices[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume', 'Market cap']] = prices[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume', 'Market cap']].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

but it gives me an error msg:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `prices[column_list] = prices[column_list].astype(float)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
prices[list_of_columns].applymap(lambda x: float(x))
```

Also, if you're really trying to just convert the values into floats, just use [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
prices[list_of_colums] = prices[list_of_columns].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `astype()` to convert the data type to float in a single line:

```
prices = prices.astype({"Open":'float', "Close":'float', "Low":'float', "Volume":'float', "Market cap":'float'})
```